# Loops with prioritization/order

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I was wondering if it was possible to prioritize code inside of `if` statements that are nested under one main one like so:

```
for blah:
    if case1:
        # takes highest priority and
        # will execute first even if
        # other cases are true
    if case2:
        # takes lower priority
    if case3:
        # takes lowest priority
```

Only thing I could find was perhaps a priority queue such as `heapq`, but I don't entirely understand how either work, or if they are relevant.

More specifically for my code:

```
for x in list_of_lists:    # x would be a list then containing multiple integers
    if 1 in x and not (2 in x or 3 in x):
        # basically just want to see if the list "x" = [1]
        # takes highest priority and
        # will execute first even if
        # other cases are true
    if 1 in x and (2 in x or 3 in x):
        # checking to see if the list "x" contains a 1 and a 2, or a 1 and a 3
        # takes lower priority
    if something similar to the above:
        # takes lowest priority
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're having two separate problems, you should post them as two questions. (I can answer your second one, but please separate them first.)

Comment: It's not so easy to understand exactly what you are asking, but for your first question: the concept you seem to be suggesting here would work. A priority queue is something completely different and bears no relation to your question. Have a read of some tutorials: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: jpmc26, apologies I will, but it says I cannot for another 90 minutes, any chance you could private message me and then I could just edit it out?

Comment: @awar Just wait 90 minutes. Also, there are no private messages on Stack Overflow (that would be completely counter to the spirit of the site).

Comment: desired login: I have clarified a little more in the comments for the first question, does that help? I want to be able to assign priorities/an order to a sequence of loops basically.

Veedrac: Bugger haha, thanks for the info!

Comment: @awar Unfortunately your example code doesn't clarify that much; it's impossible for the first *and* second option to be true! You should give a case where Python is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Haha alright I edited again for more clarity. The code has run, it behaves how I expect it to, my initial question was just to make sure the if statements followed an order that I wanted them to follow, which is the order I arranged my example. Thank to your answer below I know now that it already follows the order I place it in. The complications arose from the code I would place under each of these if statements which was where my second questions came in haha, so we'll see about that later then.

Comment: @awar Note that for this code you can write `if x == [1]` and `if x == [1, 2] or x == [1, 3]` if your comments are accurate. Glad I could help :).

Comment: Ah yes you understand correctly, your first if I feel quite silly for blanking on haha. The second if statement, with the "or", however would not read the information correctly I think, apologies again since this was again a lack of clarity. I want it to read the lists and see if it contains a 1 and a 2, or a 1 and a 3. x could be [1,3,4,5,6,7] and I want it to return true because it contains 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already the case:

```
if True:
    print(1)

if True:
    print(2)

if False:
    print(3)

if True:
    print(4)

#>>> 1
#>>> 2
#>>> 4
```

If you want to only print `1` instead, use `elif` (short for `else if`):

```
if True:
    print(1)

elif True:
    print(2)

elif False:
    print(3)

elif True:
    print(4)

#>>> 1
```

This is the same as a cascade of `if...else`, hence the `else if` contraction:

```
if True:
    print(1)

else:
    if True:
        print(2)

    else:
        if False:
            print(3)

        else:
            if True:
                print(4)

#>>> 1
```

Comment: So do I understand this correctly then: in the first case, using only if statements with no else-ifs, the loops will execute in the order I place them in? Prioritizing loops that are higher up?

Comment: The `if`s will execute in the order you write them. If you want to change the order of the `for` itself, it wasn't clear in the question (and is much harder to do). Can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ah ok I understand then. I don't think I need to change the order of the for statement, the for statement in my code is just a simple for-in reading through all the elements in a list. I edited my initial question to show you an example

Comment: @awar Basically, this boils down to the fact that Python is executed sequentially. The currect scope is always executed sequentially. So module statements are executed sequentially as are statements inside a function body. The only way to change that is to create a function using a `def` or `lambda` statement, where the body is a new scope that will be executed when called instead of immediately. (I guess strictly speaking, a class creates a new scope as well, but the statements in the class scope will be executed immediately, I believe.) Is there some specific behavior you find confusing?

Comment: My initial question has been cleared up for me thank you, I think I understand now what I wanted to with this question of order.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `if-elif` which is equivalent to `switch-case` statement like it's done [here](http://psychonauticresearch.com/switch-case-statement-in-python/)